# CS50 Recover - How do I use sprintf? error: use of undeclared identifier 'filename'; did you mean 'rename'?

Tags: c, memory, printf, cs50

CS50 is my first coding experience and I can't get past Recover. I'm taking the online free course and I'm working by myself and these problem sets are very difficult for me.  If my code and questions look novice I apologize in advance.

Some questions:

1. Am I using sprintf correctly? What do I need to use in place of the "filename" (see error)
2. Am I using the while loop correctly?
3. Am I even close to the right solution or should I quit coding at this point?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // check usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Please enter only 1 argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // open file
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover usage\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int count = 0;
    // Read first 4 bytes
    unsigned char buffer[4];
    while(fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) == 512);
    // check first 4 bytes
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff &&
        buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
        buffer[2] == 0xff &&
        (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        // count this 512B block
        {
            if (count == 0) // if first jpeg
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count); // last number is ith filename
                FILE *img = fopen(filename, "w"); // writing to filename
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, filename); // write to buffer 512 bytes at a time to filename
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(filename);
                count++; // add to existing count
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count); // last number is ith filename
                FILE *img = fopen(filename, "w"); // writing to filename
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, filename); // write to buffer 512 bytes at a time to filename
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (count > 1)
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count); // last number is ith filename
                FILE *img = fopen(filename, "a"); // writing to filename
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, filename); // write to buffer 512 bytes at a time to filename
            }
        }

    fclose(argv[1]);
}
```

Here are my error codes:
~/pset4/recover/ $ make recover
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    recover.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o recover
recover.c:33:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'filename'; did you mean 'rename'?
sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count); // last number is ith filename
^~~~~~~~
rename

recover.c:57:12: error: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'FILE *' (aka 'struct _IO_FILE *') [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
fclose(argv[1]);
^~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:199:26: note: passing argument to parameter '__stream' here
extern int fclose (FILE *__stream);
^
11 errors generated.
: recipe for target 'recover' failed
make: *** [recover] Error 1

Comment: At the risk of pointing out the obvious, I don't see a 'filename' declared anywhere in your code, so the first error doesn't seem unexpected. What do you mean for 'filename' to refer to? (Edit: I have a guess as to what it should refer to, but I'm still wondering what the intent is.)

Comment: The `fclose` function takes a `FILE*` as its argument, *not* a filename string. So, `fclose(argv[1]);` should be `fclose(file);`.

Comment: @scg Thanks for your reply.  I believe the problem is my understanding of what should be used here in place of filename.  From the lecture video it states that it should be a char array to store the resultant string for this jpg.  Does this mean I need to create a new array (ie. buffer1). And is this where I need to use malloc to allocate memory?

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you. Sorry for asking the obvious but I'm really having trouble with the names here. Do you literally mean fclose(file);  or should it be fclose(card.raw)?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues in your code. Some have 'simple' fixes, others I can only make 'intelligent guesses' at.

First, you are using a `filename` variable in which to write the name of your output files, but never declare that; this is a simple fix: declare a `char filename[512];` variable (or whatever size, in place of 512, you feel is necessary).

Second, the `fclose` function takes, as its argument, a previously-opened `FILE*` 'handle'; this will, in your code, be either the `file` variable (for the input file) or the `img` variable (for the outputs).

Third, your code uses very 'local' definitions for the `img` variable, which aren't shared between the different `if ... else` blocks; to fix this, declare the variable in a more 'outer' scope and just *use* it (*without re-declaring*) in the various other places.

Other issues are that your `while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) == 512);` statement is reading lots of times (probably) but the following code is only executed *after* that read operation fails, which is almost certainly *not* what you need; so, you should have a `{ ... }` block to enclose (most of) the following code in that `while` loop.

There are also a couple of places where I *think* you should be closing the output file: once inside the loop, where you 'reopen' a new output, and once after the whole big loop is finished, to close the 'dangling' open file handle.

I have added comments with the triple slash (`///`) in the code below, to address these points. Please feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // check usage
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Please enter only 1 argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // open file
    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Usage: ./recover usage\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int count = 0;
    /// TEST first 4 bytes
    unsigned char buffer[512]; /// This needs to be 512 bytes - not just the first 4 that you test!!
    char filename[512]; /// Buffer in which to write filename string
    FILE* img = NULL;   /// This variable MUST be in the more outer scope!
    while (fread(buffer, 1, 512, file) == 512) { /// count and size were round the wrong way!
        // check first 4 bytes
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff &&
            buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
            buffer[2] == 0xff &&
            (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            // count this 512B block
        {
            if (count == 0) { // if first jpeg
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count); // last number is ith filename
                img = fopen(filename, "w"); /// Don't (re)declare a local "img"
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img); /// Use FILE* handle, not name!
            }
            else {
                fclose(img); /// Use FILE* handle, not name!
                count++; // add to existing count
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count); // last number is ith filename
                img = fopen(filename, "w"); /// Don't (re)declare a local "img"
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img); /// Use FILE* handle, not name!
            }
        }
        else {
            if (count > 1) {
                fclose(img); /// I THINK you need to close the old file first!
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count); // last number is ith filename
                img = fopen(filename, "a"); // writing to filename
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img); // write to buffer 512 bytes at a time to filename
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(img); /// At SOME point (probably here) you should close the remaining opened output file!

    fclose(file); /// Use FILE* handle, not name!
    return 0;
}
```

Also, to be thorough, you really should be checking *every* result from the `img - fopen(...)` calls, and adding some kind of error handling if that is ever `NULL` (as you have done when opening the input file).

Comment: Also, (noticed after posting) your `buffer` variable **must** be 512 bytes, because that's how many you pump into it with each 'fread' operation, and how many you write from it in the `fwrite` calls.

Comment: And another 'late spot' - your `count` and `size` arguments to `fread` and `fwrite` are round the wrong way (edited in the answer). This will matter in the `fread` test, because it returns the number of **items,** not the number of *bytes* that were read.

Comment: I can't describe how thankful I am of your replies. I'm still registering all of them.  The buffer size was confusing for me but it makes sense now. I'm now adding checks for every result from the img - fopen (...) calls.  Using your code it returns segmentation error. I'm assuming it has something to do with this.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened before, but I'm not getting segmentation error anymore.  and the first jpg was created! I now see 000.jpg, but nothing after that. I am wondering if anything's broken with the loop. Checking right now.

Comment: @Arian Mole I think I just found it! A missing count++ in the (count == 0) clause.

Comment: fyi, this is the code I ended up submitting. Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Adrian Mole's pointers, I've completed my code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // check usage
    if (argc != 2) 
    {
        printf("Please enter only 1 argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // open file
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover usage\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int count = 0; // create count integer
    unsigned char buffer[512]; /// This needs to be 512 bytes - not just the first 4 that you test!!
    char filename[512]; // Buffer in which to write filename string
    FILE *img = NULL;   // This variable MUST be in the more outer scope!
    while (fread(buffer, 1, 512, file) == 512) // count and size were round the wrong way!
    { 
        // check first 4 bytes
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff &&
            buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
            buffer[2] == 0xff &&
            (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            // count this 512B block
        {
            if (count == 0) // if first jpeg
            { 
                count++;
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count - 1); // last number is ith filename
                img = fopen(filename, "w"); // Don't (re)declare a local "img"
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img); // using img handle
            }
            else 
            {
                fclose(img); /// Use FILE* handle, not name!
                count++; // add to existing count
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count - 1); // last number is ith filename
                img = fopen(filename, "w"); // Don't (re)declare a local "img"
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img); // Using img handle
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (count > 0) 
            {
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img); // write to buffer 512 bytes at a time to filename
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(img); // At SOME point (probably here) you should close the remaining opened output file!

    fclose(file); // Use FILE* handle, not name!
    return 0;
}
```